# Why SignalR OracleDependency does not work with the full IIS?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, iis, signalr

I want to create a website to notify me, whenever a record in my database table was changed, inserted or deleted.
So I started a hub, register my notification listener (OracleDependency) and update a record.

```
var hub = $.connection.oracleNotificationHub;
$("#btnStart").click(function ()
{
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function ()
    {
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;
        hub.server.start();
    })
});
```

After calling `hub.server.start`, this code runs:

```
using (var con = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CON"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select rowid, root from myTable where id = 1", con))
    {
        OracleDependency.Port = 1005;
        dep = new OracleDependency(cmd, false, 10000, true);
        dep.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnNotificaton);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        var txn = con.BeginTransaction();
        string updateCmdText = "update myTable set root = concat(root, '_') where id = 1";
        OracleCommand updateCmd = new OracleCommand(updateCmdText, con);
        updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        txn.Commit();
    }
}

private void OnNotificaton(object src, OracleNotificationEventArgs arg)
{
    DataTable changeDetails = arg.Details;
    OracleNotificationInfo info = (OracleNotificationInfo)changeDetails.Rows[0]["Info"];
    Write(String.Format("{0}: Data has changed in {1}, QueryId: {2}, Rowid: {3}", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), changeDetails.Rows[0]["ResourceName"], changeDetails.Rows[0]["QueryId"], changeDetails.Rows[0]["Rowid"]));

    DataChanged = true;
}
```

this code works with a console application and IIS 8 Express.

I added a firewall rule (inbound) to allow all at port 1005 (TCP). My application crashed and the notification-event is not fireing, if i run it with IIS 10.
the log from the event viewer:

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 10.0.10240.16384, timestamp: 0x559f3b1e  
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.10240.16384, timestamp: 0x559f38c3  
Exception code: 0xe0434352 Fault offset: 0x000000000002a1c8 Faulting process id: 0x1030  
Faulting application start time: 0x01d102e894da28a5  
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe  
Faulting module path:  C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll  
Report Id: 1df08a7c-be69-4b68-b2f2-6d4687db5aa9 
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Why does it not work with the full IIS?

Comment: So set some exception handling and some breakpoints and step through it to narrow down the possible range of issues. Turn off the firewall, detach Signalr and just run the oracle code. As it stands, it could be absolutely anything. You need to do some basic debugging to at least work out which component is causing the issue.

Comment: the exception is not raising at my code. the same code works within a console application and iis express! if i turn off the firewall or add the inbound rule on port 1005, the application crashed and the exception is raising... i try it to run only the oracle code tomorrow and let you know if anything has changed

Comment: same exception without SignalR. after a commit on the database, the following message pop up from visual studio: http://www.img-host.de/bild.php/58390,captureBP48F.png

Comment: it is working now with full IIS. the solution is to remove the Oracle.DataAccess component and add the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.... so simple -.-